# Correct way of initialize variables seam

Tags: java, xhtml, seam

I want to initialize a variable and want it coupled with a textfield in HTML.
When I call a function I want to use this variable to insert something in the database. But currently I keep getting a null value for the field. Any ideas ? (See code below)

Currently I have this :

```
Name("orderUploadAction")
@Scope(ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
public class OrderUploadAction implements Serializable {

    public static final int MAX_SYNC_PART_AMOUNT = 50;

    private final static String SEAM_UPLOAD = "seamUpload";
    private final static String COMMONS_UPLOAD = "commonsUpload";

    @Logger
    static Log log;

    @In
    Identity identity;

    @In(create = true)
    private ProductDao productDao;

    @In(scope = ScopeType.SESSION)
    private PortalUserHome portalUserHome;

    @In(create=true,required=false,scope=ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
    private String refNumber;


    @In
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private UploadItem uploadItem;
    private ArrayList<String> errors = null;

    @In(required=false,scope=ScopeType.CONVERSATION)
    @Out(required=false)
    private String refNumber;


    @Email
    private String email;





    public 

    // Upload Method
    boolean usedSeamBuildInUpload = true;

    // Apache Commons FileUpload
    byte[] byteArray;


    public OrderUploadAction() {

    }

    @Create
    public void init(){
        log.debug("Initing CONVERSATION component FileUploadAction...");
        uploadItem = null;
        errors = new ArrayList<String>();
        errors.clear();
        refNumber = "";

    }

    // listener for the upload function on fileUpload.xhtml
    public void listener(UploadEvent event) throws Exception {
        uploadItem = event.getUploadItem();
        log.debug("File uploaded with name: #0", uploadItem.getFileName());
    }

    public String decideWhatToDo(){

        errors = new ArrayList<String>();
        String s = refNumber;
        String x = customerOrderHome.getInstance().getReferenceNumber();
        System.out.println(s);
        if(refNumber == null || refNumber == "" ){
            errors.add("Please fill in a P.O number before starting upload");
            return "error";

        }
        else if(uploadItem == null || uploadItem.getData() == null){
                log.debug("Cannot decide, there is no file");
                log.debug("-> Decision outcome: ERROR");
                return "error";
            }
        else{
            doSyncProcessing();
            return "success";
        }







    }

    /**
     * @return the refNumber
     */
    public String getRefNumber() {
        return refNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @param refNumber the refNumber to set
     */
    public void setRefNumber(String refNumber) {
        this.refNumber = refNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @param errors the errors to set
     */
    public void setErrors(ArrayList<String> errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }

    private String doSyncProcessing() {
        return doSyncProcessing(true, false);
    }



    public String doSyncProcessing(boolean buildInSeamUpload, boolean convarFlag){
        usedSeamBuildInUpload = buildInSeamUpload;
        log.debug("Starting SYNCHRONOUS processing...");

        ByteArrayInputStream bis = null;
        if(usedSeamBuildInUpload) {
            bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(uploadItem.getData());   
        }else {
            bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteArray);  
        }

        return createOrder(null,bis,identity, convarFlag);
    }



    public String createOrder(String email,InputStream bis,Identity identity, boolean convarFlag){
        log.debug("Transforming to a Order");
        // Load the byte array to an input stream for reading.



        // Load the input stream to a buffered reader to read the data.
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(bis));

        String csvLine;
        int nextTxt = 0;
        int index = 0;
        UploadOrderItem item = new UploadOrderItem();
        ArrayList<UploadOrderItem> items= new ArrayList<UploadOrderItem>();
        // here we go...
        try {
            // start reading
            while ((csvLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                if(!csvLine.toUpperCase().contains("PRODUCTCODE")){

                    if (!(csvLine.equals("EOF"))) {

                        nextTxt = 0;
                        index = 2;

                        for(int i=0;i<csvLine.length();i++) {

                            if(csvLine.charAt(i) == ';'){
                                switch(index){

                                /*case 0:
                                    item.setCustomerSAP(Integer.parseInt(csvLine.substring(0, (i)).trim()));
                                break;*/

                                /*case 1:
                                    item.setRefPO(csvLine.substring(nextTxt,(i)).trim());
                                break;*/

                                case 2:
                                    item.setProductCode(csvLine.substring(nextTxt,(i)).trim());
                                break;

                                case 3: 
                                    try{
                                        int quantity = Integer.parseInt(csvLine.substring(nextTxt,(i)).trim());
                                        item.setQuantity(Integer.parseInt(csvLine.substring(nextTxt,(i)).trim()));
                                    }catch(Exception e){
                                        errors.add("Quantity incorrect with productcode "+item.getProductCode());
                                    }
                                break;

                                }
                                    index++;
                                    nextTxt = i +1;

                            }

                        }
                        if(csvLine.substring(nextTxt,csvLine.length()).trim().equals("Y")){

                            item.setFOC(true);

                        }
                        else if(!csvLine.substring(nextTxt,csvLine.length()).trim().equals("")){
                            errors.add("Free of charge incorrect with productcode "+item.getProductCode());
                        }
                        items.add(item);
                        item = new UploadOrderItem();

                    } else {
                        index =0;
                        break;
                    }

                }

            }


        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.debug("IOException occured when reading the CSV file.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Intern error occured while processing the CSV file!");
        }


        // close the reader
        try{
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.warn("Buffered Reader from file upload could not be closed for some reason...");
        }

        log.debug("-> Transformation done!");

        //Check items
        CustomerOrder currentOrder = new CustomerOrder();

        OrderItem oItem;

        for (UploadOrderItem ul : items) {
            oItem = new OrderItem();
            oItem.setCurrency("EUR");
            Product x = null;
            try{
                x = productDao.findProductByProductCode(ul.getProductCode());
                oItem.setProduct(x);
            }catch(Exception e){
                log.error("Error occured while getting product");
                errors.add("Error getting product for "+ul.getProductCode()+"\n");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(ul.isFOC()){
                int foc = 100;
                oItem.setDiscountType(DiscountType.PERCENTAGE);
                oItem.setDiscountValue(BigDecimal.valueOf(foc));
            }

            oItem.setQuantity(ul.getQuantity());
            oItem.setStatus(OrderStatus.INITIAL);
            oItem.setTotalNetPrice(null);
            oItem.setVatAmount(null);
            oItem.setVatRate(null);
            oItem.setTotalSurcharges(null);
            oItem.setCustomerOrder(currentOrder);
            currentOrder.getOrderItems().add(oItem);
            currentOrder.setReferenceNumber(refNumber);
        }

        String fullName = "";
        if(portalUserHome.getInstance().getFirstName() != null) {
            fullName+=  portalUserHome.getInstance().getFirstName()  + " ";
        }
        if (portalUserHome.getInstance().getLastName() != null) {
            fullName += portalUserHome.getInstance().getLastName();
        } else {
            fullName = fullName.trim();
        }

        currentOrder.setCreatorFullName(fullName);
        currentOrder.setCreatorUserName(portalUserHome.getInstance().getUserName());
        currentOrder.setCreatedOn(new Date());

        customerOrderHome.setInstance(currentOrder);

        Customer customer = entityManager.find(Customer.class, portalUserHome.getInstance()
                .getCustomer().getId());

        portalUserHome.getInstance().setCustomer(customer);

        customerOrderHome.getInstance().setCustomer(customer);
        customerOrderHome.getInstance().setAddress(customer.getDefaultAddress());

        if(errors.size()==0){
            try{
                customerOrderHome.persist();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else{
            return "error";
        }




        return "success";
    }


    /**
     * Very fast method to give an approximate number of lines in the file
     * @param data A byte[] representing the data 
     * @return int The number of lines
     * @throws IOException If IO exceptions occurs
     */
    private int count(byte[] data) throws IOException {     
        ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        try {
            byte[] c = new byte[1024];
            int count = 0;
            int readChars = 0;
            while ((readChars = is.read(c)) != -1) {
                for (int i = 0; i < readChars; ++i) {
                    if (c[i] == '\n')
                        ++count;
                }
            }
            return count;
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
    }



    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }


    // GETTERS & SETTERS



    public List<String> getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }
```

And XHTML :

```
    <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:s="http://jboss.com/products/seam/taglib"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
    xmlns:a="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:pioneer="http://www.pioneer.com/jsf"
    template="/layout/template.xhtml">


    <ui:define name="body">

        <h1>
            <h:outputText value="#{messages.upload_title}" />
        </h1>

        <div class="clearfix">

            <rich:panel>
                <script>

                    function showErrors(){
                        alert("File upload has failed please see the output below the fileupload");

                    }

                    function showComplete(){
                        alert("File successfully processed. Orders are placed.");
                    }

                </script>

                <s:div styleClass="block bgcolor-6" id="orderSearchFields">
                    <div class="hd">
                        <h3>#{messages.upload_subTitle}</h3>
                    </div>

                    <div class="bd">
                        #{messages.upload_info}<br /> #{messages.upload_csv}<br />



                        <br />

                        <s:decorate id="refNumBer" template="/layout/editShort.xhtml">
                            <h:inputText id="refNumBer"
                                value="#{orderUploadAction.refNumber}" styleClass="txt" />
                        </s:decorate>


                        <a:status for="uploadRegion"
                            onstart="Richfaces.showModalPanel('confirmWait');">
                            <f:facet name="start">
                                <h:column>
                                    <br />
                                    <h:outputText>
                                        <b>#{messages.upload_wait_process}</b>
                                    </h:outputText>
                                    <h:graphicImage value="/img/pioneer/spinner.gif" />
                                </h:column>
                            </f:facet>
                        </a:status>
                    </div>
                </s:div>
                <h:form>
                      <rich:panel id="fileUpload">
                        <a:region id="uploadRegion">
                            <rich:fileUpload
                                fileUploadListener="#{orderUploadAction.listener}" id="upload"
                                addControlLabel="Add" acceptedTypes="csv" maxFilesQuantity="1">
                                <a:support event="onuploadcomplete"
                                    action="#{orderUploadAction.decideWhatToDo()}"
                                    reRender="errorUpload,fileUpload" />
                                    <!--   oncomplete="if (#{orderUploadAction.errors.size()==0}) {showComplete();}
                                    else{showErrors();} "-->
                            </rich:fileUpload>
                        </a:region>


                    </rich:panel>

                </h:form>
                <br />

                <!--  <rich:panel id="errorUpload" rendered="orderUploadAction.errors !=0">

                    <c:forEach items="#{orderUploadAction.errors}" var="error">
                        <h:outputText value="#{error}" style="color:red">
                        </h:outputText>
                        <br />
                    </c:forEach>

                </rich:panel>-->
            </rich:panel>
        </div>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: where is your refNumber in bean class?? or any error not show??eg. doAction resolve to null...

Comment: Can't I just use a String ?

Comment: change refNumber to myNumber in xhtml Or myNumber to refNumber in bean class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to initialize variablen in your orderUploadAction.decideWhatToDo() action event.
I think your **form** tag should move to start.
eg.

```
    <h:form>
    <s:div styleClass="block bgcolor-6" id="orderSearchFields">
    ...

<s:decorate id="refNumBer" template="/layout/editShort.xhtml">
                            <h:inputText id="refNumBer"
                                value="#{orderUploadAction.refNumber}" styleClass="txt" />
                        </s:decorate>

    ...
    decideWhatToDo() action..
    ...
    </h:form>
```

Comment: Sorry myNumber is refNumber . I typed it over.

Comment: Yes got getters and setters

Comment: i see. if you want to get refNumber filed value in {orderUploadAction.decideWhatToDo() action, your  <h:form> tag should move to start.eg. above of this code.<s:div styleClass="block bgcolor-6" id="orderSearchFields">

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69277/discussion-between-david-and-ye-win).